# Intensity mapping of the 21 cm line

Tags: astrophysics, interstellar-matter

I'm currently reading [Astrophysics for physicists](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802218) by A.R. Choudhuri. Section 6.5 of his book he presents the following plot:

[image]

and tries to explain how it was generated. I'm having a hard time understanding how we can differentiate between the different velocities. As far as I understand we only measure the intensity $I(l,0)$ along the line of sight for some $l$. So I would expect that we are able to plot $I(l,0) \text{ vs. } l$, but I don't see how we can actually know how the velocity distribution of the ISM along the line of sight is.

In his book, Choudhuri talks shortly about
$$v_R = (\omega-\omega_0)R_0\sin l,$$
where $\omega_0$ and $R_0$ are the angular speed and the radius of our sun to the galactic center. I think he uses this to somehow explain how we can actually measure $I(l,0,v_R)$ instead of $I(l,0)$ but I just couldn't follow his arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the velocity can be measured by utilizing
the [Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect).

The frequency of the [21-centimeter hydrogen radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line)
is known with high precision: $f_0 = 1.420405752\, \mathrm{GHz}$.
We also know the speed of light: $c = 2.998 \cdot 10^8 \mathrm{m/s}$.

The Doppler effect is the following. When the radiating source is approaching you with velocity $v$,
then you measure a slightly higher frequency
$$f = \left(1+\frac{v}{c}\right) f_0.$$

Likewise, when the radiation source moves away from you,
then you measure a slightly lower frequency.

Hence, by measuring the frequency $f$, you can calculate the velocity
$$ v = \frac{f-f_0}{f_0} c.$$

Comment: Let's say I have two H1 clouds along my line of sight at different radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ from the galactic center. If I now measure the redshift, how do I know from what velocity I'm measuring (or to be more precise, to what does this measured velocity correspond)? Is it the velocity of cloud 1, or 2, or maybe the sum of the projections on the line of sight? In general I'm confused about how we can determine the velocity at every point along the line of sight, as indicated by the figure I posted above...

Comment: When there are several H1 clouds along your line of sight,
then you get a mixture of several frequencies (i.e. a spectrum)
according to the mixture of velocities.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. But I‘m still confused on how one now obtains $I(l,0,v_R)$. What I measure is $I(l,0)$, right? So how am I able to now figure out how this measured intensity is distributed over the measured spectrum of velocities?

Comment: I guess they used some kind of tunable radio-receiver
and just scanned through the frequency range from 
$1.419$ to $1.421\,\text{GHz}$ and measured the intensities for all frequencies.

Comment: I‘m sorry, but I can‘t follow you here.. Could you maybe explain this in a bit more detail.